# Loading data from a remote app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, tcp

I have a method which loads data from a remote app (send TCP request and parse response). Now, I have a simple class for sending a TCP request:

```
public class PremieraTcpClient
    {
        public PremieraTcpClient()
        {
            QueryItems = new NameValueCollection();
            int port;
            int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PremieraPort"], out port);
            Port = port;
            ServerIp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PremieraServerIp"];
            ServiceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PremieraServiceId"];
        }
        public NameValueCollection QueryItems { get; set; }

        private int Port { get; set; }

        private string ServerIp { get; set; }

        private string ServiceId { get; set; }

        private string ReadyQuery { get; set; }

        public string SendQuery()
        {            
            StringBuilder parameters = new StringBuilder();

            //...
            // build query for request
            //...
            ReadyQuery = parameters.ToString();            
            return Connect();            
        }

        private string Connect()
        {
            string responseData;

            try
            {
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ServerIp, Port);
                client.ReceiveBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;

                Byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(ReadyQuery);

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                // send data
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                var sizeBuffer = new byte[10];

                stream.Read(sizeBuffer, 0, 10);
                var sizeMessage = int.Parse(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(sizeBuffer, 0, 10));

                 data = new Byte[sizeMessage];

                var readSoFar = 0;
                //read data
                while (readSoFar < sizeMessage)
                {
                    readSoFar += stream.Read(data, readSoFar, data.Length - readSoFar);
                }

                responseData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(data, 0, data.Length);                
                responseData = responseData.TrimStart('&');               
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
                return responseData;
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                //return responseData = string.Format("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                //return responseData = string.Format("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }    
    }
```

This is method for load data:

```
 private static void GetUpdatesFromPremiera()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ":GetUpdatesFromPremiera");

            PremieraTcpClient client = new PremieraTcpClient();
            client.QueryItems.Add("QueryCode", QueryCode.GetUpdates.ToString());
            client.QueryItems.Add("ListType", "Movie;Hall;Session;Place;Delete");
            client.QueryItems.Add("Updates", _lastUpdateId);
            _lastUpdateId = String.Empty;
            var response = client.SendQuery();

            // here parse response
            //...
        }
```

This code works fine. But, now I have to load data from two remote app (tomorrow may be three).

The simple solution is to iterate through all remote apps:

```
private static void GetUpdatesFromPremiera()
{
   foreach(var remoteApp in listRemoteApp)
   {
        PremieraTcpClient client = new PremieraTcpClient();
        // here assigned different properties
        var response = client.SendQuery();
   }
}
```

Is there is a better way of doing it? Also, each time a connection is established, I think it impacts performance greatly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. If you have a collection of items, using `foreach` to do something for each item is exactly what you should be doing. I certainly don't think it's ugly.

Comment: @svick:ok, What you think about `PremieraTcpClient`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have some suggestions about PremieraTcpClient. The way it is written may lead to unreleased resources. If you have an error then you will remain with a ***stream*** and ***client***  opened.
The correct way to do it is by using ***try...catch...finally*** or by using ***using***.
Below you can find the code using try catch finally

```
    private string Connect()
    {
        string responseData = string.Empty;
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream stream = null; 
        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient(ServerIp, Port);
            client.ReceiveBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;

            Byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(ReadyQuery);

            stream = client.GetStream();

            // send data
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            var sizeBuffer = new byte[10];

            stream.Read(sizeBuffer, 0, 10);
            var sizeMessage = int.Parse(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(sizeBuffer, 0, 10));

            data = new Byte[sizeMessage];

            var readSoFar = 0;
            //read data
            while (readSoFar < sizeMessage)
            {
                readSoFar += stream.Read(data, readSoFar, data.Length - readSoFar);
            }

            responseData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = responseData.TrimStart('&');
            //stream.Close();
            //client.Close();
            //return responseData;
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            //return responseData = string.Format("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            //return responseData = string.Format("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(stream!=null) stream.Close();
            if(client!=null) client.Close();
        }

        return responseData;
    }
```

And another small suggestion: I think is misleading to have a method named **Connect** that in fact does more than connect. It will be better to break the Connect method into smaller methods, each one with specific actions (even if they are private).